# pass in command in 'exec form' with docker run

Tags: docker

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd says that in a Dockerfile

```
CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]
```

is the 'exec form' and

```
CMD command param1 param2
```

is the 'shell form', and they are run slightly differently.

> Note: Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell

But when you are passing in the command with `docker run`, I can find any way to make it run without a command shell.

```
docker run container-name echo test # shell form I guess
```

What is the exec form?

Comment: I don't believe you can. If you want to use the JSON form of CMD, just write a Dockerfile.

Comment: Exec form is more related to dockerfile and not available in Docker run. And it doesn't even make sense for a docker run command

Answer (score 2):

Why guessing? Just check.

```
docker run ubuntu sh -c 'echo "Hello world!"'
```

creates a container one may discover with `docker container ls -a`
and inspect by id.

The inspect command reveals that *no additional sh -c* was added except the explicit one:

```
"Cmd": [
    "sh",
    "-c",
    "echo \"Hello world!\""
],
```

Thus current hypothesis is that it uses **exec form**.
Just to mention: my tests for `docker-compose run` have shown the same results.

This is very poorly documented both for [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options) and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/), that's true. The `--entrypoint` option is slightly luckier and is documented at [dockerfile docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example):

> You can override the ENTRYPOINT setting using --entrypoint, but this can only set the binary to exec (no sh -c will be used).